# How can i have where clause in Nested queries with select statement that returns more than 1 records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am currently trying to make an nested query of some sort where it returns a set of rows which fulfills a particular set of requirements..

```
select * from entity 
 where id = (
 select attribute_entity_id from attribute 
 where attribute_type_specification_id = (
 select id from attribute_type_specification  
 where entity_internal_name = 'country'
 )
 ) 
 order by entity_id
```

Though this returns error:

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Which is true, but how i should make this call then? The inner select might return x number of id's which are valid?

Comment: Use `in` instead of `=`.

Comment: Use EXISTS instead of IN or scalar subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you are using subselects to accomplish this?

The regular way to do this is with joins:

```
select e.*, ats.entity_internal_name
  from entity e
  join attribute a
    on a.attribute_entity_id = e.id
  join attribute_type_specification ats
    on ats.id = a.attribute_type_specification_id
 where ats.entity_internal_name = 'country'
 order by e.entity_id 
;
```

Comment: Would be possible to join specific columns value from that entry where the condition was valid?  I would instance like to know the colulmn value internal_name on alle the id where the condition nested in the query was true

Comment: @kafka  You can put whatever columns you want in the select list.  I added an example of how to add `attribute_type_specification.entity_internal_name`.